# rake -T ... noglob: command not found

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, rake

When I run `rake -T` I get the message `noglob: command not found` and the Rake task doesn't run. It's in a Bash shell on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

D'oh. There was an alias in `.bash_aliases`: `alias rake="noglob rake"`. I removed it and sourced the file as well as `~/.bashrc` and `.profile`. However, to take effect I had to re-login. By the way `noglob` is for ZSH.